# What fraction of the mixture by weight is pineapple?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A fruit salad is made from pineapples, pear, and peaches mixed in the ratio of $2$ to $3$ to $5$ respectively by weight. What fraction of the mixture by weight is pineapple? 
A) 1/5
B) 3/10
C) 2/5
D) 1/2
E) 2/3

Comment: tell us what you did so far...

Comment: For some $x$ you have that the weights of pineapples, pear, peaches are respectively $2x,3x,5x$. So what is the total weight? Hence what is fraction of the weight is pineapples?

Answer (score 1):

You can think that each piece of fruit is $x$ grams. Now pineapple is $2x$ grams, pear is $3x$ grams and peach is $5x$ grams. Total is $2x + 3x + 5x = 10x$ grams. Therefore pineapples are $\frac{2x}{10x} = \frac{1}{5}$ of the whole mix

Comment: 12-n, 12, 12+n
What is the average (arithmetic mean) of the 3 quantities in the list above?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. What are these 12-n 12 12+n? And why do you need the average? If I have understood your question correctly, you ask what part of the whole mix is pineapple, right?

Comment: sir i am also suspense. i got these from test user guide which is for SAT tes?

Comment: Well then I guess that my solution is correct. At least this is what I would write if I were on SAT :) Do you have answer sheet? You could check whether the answer is 1/5

Comment: i do not have sir answer sheet only question sheet as i have.

Comment: @Muhammadismail A) 1/5 is the correct answer. So why not mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: sir there is another question.... If x and y are positive integer what are the solution (x, y) of the equation 3x + 2y = 11?

Comment: @Muhammadismail  For the question $3x + 2y = 11$, notice that $11 - 3x = 2y$, so $11 - 3x$ is an even number.  For which positive integer values of $x < 11/3$ is $11 - 3x$ an even number?  Use the answer to that question to determine the possible $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: I can only agree with the comment above. Although don't ask another question(not related to the original one) in the comments, ask a new question instead.